# Fail to boot, times out waiting for device,

Tags: boot

After a regretful bad power off, my Ubuntu instalation fails to boot, the error is:
`Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2did-usb\x2dNORELSYS_1081CS1_0123456789ABCDE\x2d0:1.device (...)`

I've looked at other posts apparently related but following those guides gives more doubts, as the suggested fixes make no sense according to what I see in my computer's files.

If someone can help me it would be incredible as I'm not very happy about the idea of a new installation.

As I'm not able to copy paste my computer's output, I didn't write any more info, but I'll gladly provide any info you request.

Also I'm not using any kind of USB storage unless if it would be internal but I don't think that would be the case.

Comment: Does this help? -> https://www.google.com/search?q=norelsys+1081+usb+device

Comment: Well maybe the device in question is the pc sd card reader, but I don't really understand how it can brick the boot process, my /etc/fstab file seems different from other people's that I saw with simillar issues so I'm kinda lost at this point, troubleshooting mounts at boot is too much for my knowledge of linux, thankfully what I'm working on right know is Docker based so I'm just using Windows at the moment

Comment: But it does make sense that the card reader is connected internally via USB

Comment: Although it should not be necessary to boot ...

Comment: Well, failing hardware may give strange effects.

Comment: Well I never managed to make the incorporated sd card reader to work with linux with this MSI laptop, it only works on windows, this boot problem started when I forced the pc to shutdown while booting, I was in a hurry, I regret it, and I'm never gonna do it again, but yeah, the hardware actually works fine with windows, so I doubt that would be the case, I suppose I corrupted something, well I guess I'll do a clean install once I have the time, just sad because I'd rather be working on linux than windows